# How could I open an individual python file (or any code file) in an editor from the comand ( os.system (Path) ) or (os.startfile(path/Filename))?

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code, os.system

I am creating a script that opens an external file through two methods:

```
os.system(Path)
```

or

```
os.startfile(Path)
```

This works for Test files, however, it runs all code files like python which gets executed. I would like the option to open it in a text editor.

How would I do this in a python 2.7 script?

The text editor I use is VS Code.

Comment: Would it be something like a File extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one, but first, read the docs on what `os.system` and `os.startfile` does.

---

[`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.system)

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.

So this basically runs the *command* string you pass to it. If your intention is to open a file in VS Code, then you need to check if you can use the [VS Code command for opening files/folders from the command line](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-files-and-folders):

```
code myfile.py
```

If that works on your terminal, then your Python script would basically just be:

```
os.system("code myfile.py")
```

---

[`os.startfile(path[, operation])`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.startfile)

> Start a file with its associated application.
>
> When operation is not specified or `'open'`, this acts like double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, or giving the file name as an argument to the start command from the interactive command shell: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its extension is associated.

I assume you are on Windows, because `startfile` is only available on Windows.

The main thing here is that `startfile` is the same behavior as double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer. So, first make sure that when you double-click on a file, that it opens in VS Code. If it doesn't, then you need to associate that file with VS Code first. This is usually done by right-click > "Opens with.." then selecting VS Code from the list.

[image]

Once double-clicking on a file opens it in VS Code, then your Python script would simply be:

```
os.startfile("myfile.py", "open")
```

The `"open"` here is optional, but I prefer to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this:

```
os.system('code test_01.py')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: i cannot do this because i want to have the default opening for python files to be executed when clicked.